# Content type publishing: server impact on crawling for new subscribers?

Tags: 2013, content-type, content-type-hub

Assume you have 100.000+ site collections that subscribe to a single content type hub containing around 10 published content types.

How does the content type publishing timer job works? Does it iterate through all site collections on every run to check if there are new subscribers?
Or is it intelligent enough to know which site collections are new since last run?